# sp_db_sendmail error

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, sp-send-dbmail

I am currently running SQL Server 2014 and trying to execute a stored procedure that sends out an email using sp_db_sendmail which is failing with the following error.

> An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load
>   assembly id 65549. The server may be running out of resources, or the
>   assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or
>   UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to
>   solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this
>   error:  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'sqlwebrequest, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A) System.IO.FileLoadException:
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)

Originally the sp_db_sendmail was working but since moving the database that calls the code to a new server I am getting the above message.

I have made the owner of the database the same as it was on the original server "sa" and also set the database to be "Trustworthy" which seems according to relevant googling should fix the problem, but still no luck.

Any further suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue when moving to MS SQL 2017... The solution was to change the permission set to SAFE in the assembly

Comment: Hi jigga, can you tell me how you can do this please?

Comment: is your assembly with the id 65549 a user defined one or a system assembly?

Comment: I am going to say system assembly as I don't remember ever defining anything!

Comment: use this to find out: SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies WHERE assembly_id = 65549           also please post your query

Comment: Well I have an entry in the table Microsoft.SqlServer.Types with is_user_defined = 0 and permission_set_desc UNSAFE_ACCESS....this is exactly the same on the source server though!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167247/discussion-between-jigga-and-pjd).

Comment: I had missed one of the database's that needed to be set to Trustworthy which was causing the original issue, once set this fixed the issue!